# Remove nofollow from internal comment links via functions.php

Tags: functions, comments

When someone leaves an internal link in the comments, rel="nofollow" is automatically added. How can I remove rel="nofollow" on all internal comment links left by visitors, while retaining nofollow for external links?

Comment: you can customise that with the filter [make_clickable_rel](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/make_clickable_rel/)

Comment: This post could help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8817/how-to-remove-the-click-here-to-cancel-reply-link-from-the-wordpress-comment-f